# Back End мобильного приложения

Tags: сервер, хостинг, архитектура, клиент-сервер

Возникла необходимость создать клиент-серверное приложение под *Android*.

Возможно ли реализовать серверную часть на *PHP*, например, и расположить на обычном хостинге?

Или как это сделать более правильно и на каком языке, если нет возможности содержать собственные сервера?

Comment: *если нет возможности содержать собственные сервера?* - на самом деле есть. Сейчас полно облачных сервисов (digital ocean, amazon, миллиард мелких), которые предоставляют VPS практически за те же деньги.

Comment: @Алексей, Серверную часть возможно реализовать на PHP. В чем вопрос то?

Comment: Вопрос состоит в том как это лучше сделать? Как это делают другие, если подразумевать возможность интерграции с iOS приложением?

Answer (score 2):

Серверное приложение можно написать почти на любом языке программирования.
C, C++, javascript, PHP, C# и т.д.
Конечно на PHP это сделать относительно легко...
Посмотрите как создаются RESTful API сервисы - мне кажется это самый правильный путь для создания бекенда для апликации.

Comment: А как iOS относится к Rest'у ? не будет проблем с интерграцией?

Comment: Совершенно не важно из какой операционной системы отправлять запросы на сервер :)